# reset sequence of numbers

Tags: sort

I have 50 lines of code

```php
private const CODE = 0;
private const DESC = 1;
// ... 
private const TRIM = 19; // instead of 24
private const SMURF = 35; // instead of 25
private const DOG = 31; // instead of 26
// ... 
private const CAT = 49;
private const AMOUNT = 50;
```

As you can see, numbers are not sorted right.
I'd like to rewrite them so that I get the following instead:

```php
private const CODE = 0;
private const DESC = 1;
// ... 
private const TRIM = 24;
private const SMURF = 25;
private const DOG = 26;
// ... 
private const CAT = 49;
private const AMOUNT = 50;
```

Comment: @klaus thx, done

Comment: @klaus yeah that's I meant :D

Comment: I and several others have added answers, check them out. But if you're trying to set up a set of constants in C, I would advise using enumerations to do that. Just do, `enum { CODE, DESC, .... , TRIM, SMURF, DOG, ... , CAT, AMOUNT }` This is AFAIK the preferred way of setting up a set of related constants. I am a little hazy on the Java aspect though. But I can vaguely remember Java also having enums to do the same. You need to check out stackoverflow for this. Both for Java and C/CPP.

Comment: @klaus most of the C-like langs have enums (java, c#)

Comment: OP, is it acceptable to rearrange the lines instead of changing the number?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is the following.

Prepare: Execute `:set virtualedit=block`. This allows visual block selection (`<Ctrl-V`>) beyond the end of line.

1. Visually select the lines and execute `:'<,'>s/=.*$//` (this also deletes all trailing comments!)
2. Go to the end of the first line and hit `<C-V>` and move down over all 50 lines and to the right, so the right side of the visual box is behind all variable names.
3. Enter `A= 0;<esc>`, to append the text `= 0;` to all lines.
4. Go to the **second** line and move to the `0`.
5. Hit `<C-V>` again and move down to the last line. You have now one column visually selected.
6. Hit `g<Ctrl-A>`. This will replace the `0`s with a increasing sequence of numbers.

Comment: What if the variable names are so long that you can't use visual-block-mode properly. And if the variable names contain integers then `g<Ctrl-A>` would also edit the variable names.

Comment: @klaus 1. With `virtualedit=block` you can do blockselect beyond the end of line. So the `A = 0;<esc>` will insert text beyond all variable names. 2. When using `g<Ctrl-A>` you only have the column with the `0`s selected (steps 4 to 6).

Answer (score 2):

Assume there has no negative numbers.

```
let @"=-1 | global /\v\w+\s*\=\s*\d+\s*;/ exec("normal! f;bviwp\<c-a>yiw")
```

- `let @"=-1` set register " to -1
- `global /\v\w+\s*\=\s*\d+\s*;/` find all line that need to be changed

  - `\w+\s*\=\s*` match `"CODE = "` in `"CODE = 0;"`
  - `\d+\s*;` match `"0;"` in `"CODE = 0;"`
- `exec("normal! f;bviwp\<c-a>yiw")` execute a tiny script on each matched line:

  - `f;b` locate cursor at number before ;
  - `viwp` replace current number with register "
  - `\<c-a>` increase current number
  - `yiw` set register " to current number

Answer (score 2):

1. At first make every digit zero:

   ```
   :%s/\vprivate const .* = \zs\d*\ze;/0/g
   ```
2. Then goto the first line with `gg`
3. Then start recording. Just press <kbd>q</kbd> twice, i.e. `qq`. The first `q` will start the recording and the second `q` will define in which register (`:reg q`) the recording will be stored.
4. Goto the digit before `;` by pressing `t;`
5. Yank the integer with `yiw`
6. Go one line below, goto before `;` and put the integer in place of the zero there and increment. The whole process should be done by `j0t;viw"0p<Ctrl-A>`
7. Stop recording by pressing `q` once.
8. Perform the task from 4 to 7 with `50@q`

Comment: 1. make them zero, 2. visually select lines needed, 3. `g<C-a>`

Comment: I didn't know you can use `:h v_g_CTRL-A` with visual lines. I knew it was applicable only for visual-block-mode! Thanks.

Comment: That's true, but I doubt his/her constants have any numbers in names. In that case try to select blockwise excluding those names :)

Comment: Thanks, never know :h v_g_CTRL-A

Comment: @MaximKim, I didn't use `g<C-a>` even though I knew I can use it in visual-block-mode, because there is a chance that some variable names are just too long. In that case, you can't use visual-block-mode to visually select all the integers. It's unlikely that's the case though. By the way, I think OP should use enumerations to achieve what s/he is trying to do, shouldn't s/he?

Comment: Well, as a one off solution I will use gctrlA and deal with errors if any. For bulletproof stuff I will use smth like yours.